# Matplotlib reverse order of legend (X axis), but leave graph direction the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

Basically I have a chart where the X axis is 1, 2, 3, 4... and I want it to be ...4, 3, 2, 1.
I al ready tried with plt.gca().invert_xaxis(), and also [::-1] (reverse array order) to invert the X axis, but those will flip the entire graph direction which is exactly what I want to avoid. I want to keep the same direction of the graph with the numbers in the x axis in reverse order.

Comment: See [Setting Ticks and Tick labels](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matplotlib/matplotlib_setting_ticks_and_tick_labels.htm) in the documentation.

Comment: It worked man, but unfortunately now the x axis coordinates doesn't display where you are when you hover your mouse over the graph, it just doesn't display anything: x=

Comment: It would help if you produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).